# Amazon S3 multipart upload programmatically from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am able to find a lot of articles talking about how to do Amazon S3 multipart upload using Node.js.
But what I intend is to do it through maybe javascript or jquery from browser.
Can anybody shed some light on how to achieve this? A complete example would be great.

I can imagine the steps would probably include:

1. get a presigned url from web back end.
2. divide the large file to multiparts and upload those parts concurrently.
3. complete the upload if all the parts are successfully uploaded.